# How to write a function that check the result of a bash command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a simple function to debug my script easily and making my code simpler. (Still stuck after 3 hours)

I want to pass to this function 3 arguments

1. A command
2. A success string
3. And an error string

The function is supposed to execute the command and print the proper string whether it's a success or not.
What I mean by successful is when the command prints something in the output.

Here is what I've tried (On CentOS7) :

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD=$(yum list installed | egrep "yum.utils.\w+" | cut -d " " -f1)
SUCCESS="YES"
ERROR="NO"
foo() {
if ["$1" != ""]; then
    echo -e "$2"
else
    echo -e "$3"
fi
}
foo $CMD $SUCCESS $ERROR
```

Unfortunately, I'm encountering 2 problems :

- Firstly, when the $CMD is empty, the first parameter will be $SUCCESS instead of an empty string (the behaviour I want)
- Secondly, I want to remove the console output (> /dev/null 2>&1 ???).

Do you think it's possible? Do you have any idea how to do it?
Otherwise, is there an easier way with the eval command?

Thanks for reading and have a nice day,

Valentin M.

### ------------------ Correction ------------------

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD=$(yum list installed | grep -E "yum.utils.\w+" | cut -d " " -f1)
SUCCESS="YES"
ERROR="NO"
foo() {
if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
    echo -e "$2"
else
    echo -e "$3"
fi
}
foo "$CMD" "$SUCCESS" "$ERROR"
```

I found out a similar topic here: [Stack overflow : How to write a Bash function that can generically test the output of executed commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42529562/9914294)

Comment: Paste your code at https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Several issues.  First, remember to quote your variables: `foo "$CMD" "$SUCCESS" "$ERROR"`.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, I'm encountering 2 problems :
>
> - Firstly, when the $CMD is empty, the first parameter will be $SUCCESS instead of an empty string (the behaviour I want)

If you follow the suggestion in William Pursell's comment above, this problem is solved, since an empty first parameter is then passed.

> - Secondly, I want to remove the console output (> /dev/null 2>&1 ???).

I assume by *console output* you mean the output to STDERR, since STDOUT is assigned to `CMD`. Your `> /dev/null 2>&1` is unsuitable, as it redirects also STDOUT to `/dev/null`; just do this with STDERR:

```
CMD=$(yum list installed 2>/dev/null | egrep "yum.utils.\w+" | cut -d " " -f1)
```

Comment: Yes, that's what i needed for my first problem.
But for the second I don't want the command to write to STDOUT and STDERR either.
I just want to store the result of the command in a variable.

Comment: Edit : Finally it seems to work the way I want. It's not prompting the result of the command to my console.

Comment: You do _want the command to write to STDOUT_, because that's exactly what gets stored in `CMD`.